# How do you convert text column data with Ruby JSON format ("key" => "value") to standard JSON?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have data in the `comment` column of the `payments` table. The data is stored as plain text in the following format:

```
{"foo"=>"bar"}
```

I need to query the value of the specific `"foo"` key and tried the following:

```
select comment::json -> 'foo' from payments
```

but because the data stored is not in JSON format I get the following error:

```
invalid input syntax for type json DETAIL: Token "=" is invalid. CONTEXT: JSON data, line 1: {"foo"=>"bar"}
```

which refers to the `=>` that Ruby uses for Hashes.

Is there a way to convert the text data to JSON data on-the-fly so I can then access the specific keys I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `=>` with a `:` to make that example a valid JSON value:

```
replace(comment, '=>', ':')::jsonb ->> 'foo'
```

Comment: Thanks. The data returned is wraped in double quotes "" . I need to compare that against string data that is not wrapped in double quotes. Is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: @pinkfloyd90: I don't understand the question. The `->>` operator returns a "text" value without quotes.

Comment: The data returned by the replace function is `"foo"`, but the data I need to compare that against is stored as `foo` so the values are not equal because of the double quotes.

Comment: Which is what `->>` will do: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6329573ec911864dae75af0ba6e9e45e

Comment: That is weird. I get the same result except wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: Are you using `->` instead of `->>`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the data is technically valid ruby which means we can do something a bit clever.

```
require 'json'
def parse_data(data_string)
  eval(data_string).to_json
end
```

Should do the trick so long as the data is trusted.